# Can you calculate the probability of complement conditional

Tags: probability, statistics

> Given $P(A|B) = x$, what can you say about $P(\overline{A}|B)$?

Can we say $1 - x$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negation of Bayes' theorem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583266/negation-of-bayes-theorem)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a fairly circuitous presentation of ideas at best, starting with an incorrect statement of conditional probability (or of Bayes' Theorem, hard to say).  I don't think it makes a compelling duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can. The same question is answered in this 
[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/583290/228959).

Comment: If that answers this question as well, you should flag this one as a duplicate.